# Shared code base not possible for Web and Mobile in Flutter (?)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, hummingbird

I see following error when I try to merge mobile and web codebase in Flutter:

```
webdev could not run for this project.
This version of webdev does not support the `build_daemon` protocol used by your version of `build_runner`.
Please add a dev dependency on `build_daemon` with constraint: >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
pub finished with exit code 78
```

My `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

````
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.2.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  # Enables the `pub run build_runner` command
  build_runner: ^1.1.2
  # Includes the JavaScript compilers
  build_web_compilers: ^1.0.0

# flutter_web packages are not published to pub.dartlang.org
# These overrides tell the package tools to get them from GitHub
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui```

I'm confused about how can "shared code" can really be "shared" across multi-platform in Flutter (shared codebase being the most important feature in Flutter pitch)
````

Comment: Remove the flutter_test dependency - and dart can be compiled into JavaScript which is how they can pull off flutter for web and native platforms.

Comment: @AdrianMurray: Sorry, I had wrong code snippet before. I updated code and respective error. Thanks for helping out !

Comment: I'm seeing there are some differences in your pubspec vs what is shown on the repositroy: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web#use-flutter_web-packages-from-git

Comment: namely the build_runner and build_web_compilers. You're using 'any' where the error is asking for specific constraints. This is in your dev_dependencies

Comment: I updated all deps same as https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web#use-flutter_web-packages-from-git, still same problem

Comment: Wondering if Flutter team has any examples for web + android/ios together in same project/shared code way. I see they have separate repo for web in samples: https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/web

Comment: web and android/ios can't use the same codebase right now as web is still in preview and using a completely different dependency (flutter_web). As for your issue, take a look here: https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/375#issuecomment-491412030

Comment: oh...ok. I wasn't aware of that. I was trying to run android/ios from web, and ran into these issue. I can run web fine. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can create another project using the code you've written for ios/android, but it can't be the same project. This assumes you aren't using any plugins in that code as web doesn't have a plugin system.

Comment: You might find this article helpful: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments that it's not possible at this moment to be able to share web and native code base in one project. Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md) if you've come across this post. It has instructions on the workaround available by Flutter team.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I am working on is using javascript native in flutter by dart proxy.  Copy your javascript code under Web/src  and in the index.html file. script src the javascript code.  In your main.dart import dart:js as js and use js.context.callMethod('your function',[your parameters] to invoke the javascript method.

I am forced too use javascript because flutter does not support qr reader for chrome.